# Download/View files when clicked:Apache directory listings

Tags: php, apache2

I have a version management system made with php.

Files are added to repositories via upload.The files are stored in the sub folders of web root.(This is not an issue since it is to be run in a local network among trusted users).I have to add an option to view "raw code" or at the least download them.My current idea is to implement it using the standard apache directory listing.

**Issue**

The repositories will surely contain HTML as well as PHP files.They get executed instead of being displayed.

I tried managing it with file permissions but had no success.

Another possible solution is using a *read-only text field*,which causes a huge burden to the server memory if the file is too large.And it doesn't support image files.

Apache directory listing needs zero code to display files.Thats the main reason i chose this approach. 
Anyway here is the text field display i mentioned.

```
public function show_file()
   {
     while(!feof($this->_handle))
     {
       $content=fgets($this->_handle)."<br/>";
     }
     echo "<input type=text value=$content readonly>";
   }
```

I would consider using Javascript only as the last option,as it is completely alien to me.

How can this situation be tackled?Is there a way to exclude a particular directory(and its sub directories) from the web server?

Comment: What's the situation again? You want to display the raw PHP code instead of it being displayed?

Comment: yes,All possible files that have a chance to be executed on a web browser.......

Comment: How are you trying to display the file content? Can we see some code?

Comment: Why are you shoving the entire content of a file in an `<input>` tag anyways?  If you want to make it editable, wouldn't you want to use a `<textarea>` instead?

Comment: I have least expertise in html...Anyways,the solution creates the memory issue i said about.Although this is to be run on a local network,it will be used by numerous users simultaneously.the app manages academic student projects.just think of the scenario of opening the large files like documentations

Answer (score 0):

How about changing the suffix of the file when its uploaded? EG myfile.php becomes myfile.php.removeme? Then change it back if the person wants to download the file.

Comment: I have a script that uses php to display directory lists and then download them,But they still dont have the flexibility of the apache directory listing..I have updated my question,please check that..

Comment: what are you lacking? PHP can get all the file attributes. You could make the link different for a given file type: view, download, password, etc

Comment: It is actually for a project/code evaluation routine..you cant expect the professors go around clicking dir name then submit,times over and over

Comment: If you don't want to read directly from the filesystem you could upload the files, abstract the names into a db and then generate your pages from that. This would give you version control, source/dl control and filesystem independence.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) instead.  According to the docs:

> **file_get_contents()** is the preferred way to read the contents of a file into a string. It will use memory mapping techniques if supported by your OS to enhance performance.

For your particular case, I'd do something like:

```
$file = file_get_contents('/path/to/your/file.php');

// If you want to be able to edit the file.
echo '<textarea name="content">' . $file . '</textarea>';

// If you just want to display the content.
echo '<pre>' . htmlentities($file) . '</pre>';
```